# how to check whether a user opened the mail we sent

Tags: c#, .net, email, amazon-web-services

Using Amazon AWS we can know how many mails are delivered,how many bounced and how many were rejected.But how to check whether user has opened our mail and clicked on the link we have given in our mail.And using getsendstatistics() method of AWS we can only get the number of bounces,rejects and delivered mails.Is there any method which gives us the details whether a user opened his mail or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to do this.

You could make a webserver that serves an image (just a white pixel would do) and have it report if the image is loaded or not, perhaps even include a querystring to identify the user loading the image. The problem with this is that any modern mailclient will not load images in the email by default.

Comment: That's not true, Gmail does load images by default, and this is a well-known technique that works. Also, including other images in the email that the user actually *wants* to see increases the chances of the user clicking "load images".

Comment: And Outlook (both local and web client) does not, which is a big group of users to consider. Trying to get the user to 'trust' the message by including other content might work, but again, there are plenty of users that won't do so (for example, mobile users in Europe that try and save data usage because of their expensive plan will have email images turned off). All in all, this is not a reliable method.

Comment: Your answer states that *any modern mailclient* will not load images though.

Answer (score 0):

The mail protocol allows for two different methods (mail header entries) to request a "receipt" when the receiver opened the mail. If activated you will get a mail back which contains the receipt along with time and mail client infomation.

It is completely optional if the receiving client will honor the request however, so these methods may help but are not reliable at all.

From [wikipedia article about Email tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_tracking)

> The technical term for these is "MDN - Message Disposition
>   Notifications", and they are requested by inserting one or more of the
>   following lines into the email headers: "X-Confirm-Reading-To:";
>   "Disposition-Notification-To:"; or "Return-Receipt-To:".

Comment: how does this work.Could you give some example using C# or a link where i can find how to implement the mail protocol